# how to get all countries w/ corresponding RegionInfo.GeoId

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

As I've seen, not all countries are listed with `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)`

If I look at the dialog below, I can see the missing countries are there. How can I get this complete list (with corresponding `RegionInfo.GeoId`) from .Net?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/22d7ef4169.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/22d7ef4169.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't do this (at least not using `CultureInfo` from .NET).
[`CultureInfo` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) says:

> **Remember that the culture names and identifiers represent only a subset of cultures that can be found on a particular computer**. Windows versions or service packs can change the available cultures. Applications add custom cultures using the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class. Users add their own custom cultures using the Microsoft Locale Builder tool. Microsoft Locale Builder is written in managed code using the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class.

I have also been bitten by this and I have come to a conclusion that it is a poor practice anyway to rely business behaviour of my application on Microsoft's decisions about adding or removing cultures to .NET.

Comment: is there a way to get this via p/invoke then?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried. I just went with including ISO-3166 tables in my application.